# Click on jQuery Sortable list does not blur input

Tags: jquery, input, jquery-ui-sortable, blur

I can blur my input by clicking anywhere on the page except the jQuery Sortable list. How can I fix this?
UPD: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/43Wbh/)

Comment: Can you post your code? There can be many answers to your problem depending on your code.

Comment: even better create a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I don't think I have any special code. To play with this bug you can create an input with your browser's developer tools on this page: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('sortable').mousedown(function(){
  document.activeElement.blur();
});
```

Comment: I searched for hours to find out why input.onBlur is not fired. Until I found out that it is because of the sortable.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [cancel](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-cancel) option from the jquery-ui

```
   $("#sortable").sortable(cancel: 'input');
```

You'll have to remove the `$("#sortable").disableSelection();`

See my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guDZp/)

**UPDATE**

I understand your problem. Because jQuery stops the default functionality of the browser when sorting a list, the blur is never called for that field. You'll have to force the field to blur.

See my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43Wbh/2/). I use change to call the blur, you can change 'change' to 'start' if you want the blur to always happen.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug of jquery sortable, which will be fixed in jqueryui 2.0.0. See [Sortable: clicking a sortable item does not cause form element to blur](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7941)

Answer (score 1):

To limit the handle to a specific element that is not a input solved it for me.

Comment: Using the option handle: ".handle" (jquery selector) fixed the issue. Thanks!